# Using KSOAP2 In Android App with two Modules

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ksoap2

I'm trying to develop an Android App with two modules.

App module is my application.
Lib module is a lib to encapsulate some reutilizable code.

I will need KSOAP2 lib at both modules, and I put the *.jar KSOAP file inside lib folder at both modules, but my app doesn't compile.

So, can anyone help-me?

Here, is the build.gradle files for both modules

**App module**

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 20
        buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.regazzo.inventariowms"
            minSdkVersion 16
            targetSdkVersion 20
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()

        maven {
            url "http://dl.bintray.com/journeyapps/maven"
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

        compile files('libs/ksoap2-android-assembly-3.4.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar')
        //compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
        //compile 'com.beardedhen:androidbootstrap:+'
        // Supports Android 4.0.3 and later (API level 15)
        compile 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:2.0.1@aar'
        // Supports Android 2.1 and later (API level 7), but not optimal for later Android versions.
        // If you only plan on supporting Android 4.0.3 and up, you don't need to include this.
        compile 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-legacy:2.0.1@aar'
        // Convenience library to launch the scanning and encoding Activities.
        // It automatically picks the best scanning library from the above two, depending on the
        // Android version and what is available.
        compile 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-integration:2.0.1@aar'
        // Version 3.0.x of zxing core contains some code that is not compatible on Android 2.2 and earlier.
        // This mostly affects encoding, but you should test if you plan to support these versions.
        // Older versions e.g. 2.2 may also work if you need support for older Android versions.
        compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.0.1'
        compile project(':baselib')
    }
```

**Lib Module**

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 21
        buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

        defaultConfig {
            minSdkVersion 16
            targetSdkVersion 21
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

        compile files('libs/ksoap2-android-assembly-3.4.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar')
    }
```